# Swift 3.0 Delegate Protocol doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have made delegate protocol within two view controllers. but the delegate method doesn't call on my code snippet. what is the reason for that. I couldn't find out the issue kindly post your suggestions to relive this issue.

**Main View controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, testDelegateMethod {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let vw = testViewController()
    vw.delegateTest = self

    let push = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push!, animated: true)
}

func testMethod(value:String) {
    print("Hai", value)
}
}
```

**Sub View controller**

```
protocol testDelegateMethod {
func testMethod(value:String)
}

class testViewController: UIViewController {
var delegateTest : testDelegateMethod?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func actSubmit(_ sender: Any) {
    delegateTest?.testMethod(value: "Hello how are you!")
}

}
```

Comment: is not `vw.delegateTest = self` it is `push.delegateTest = self`, no need of this `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push!, animated: true)`

Comment: You are making object of testViewController(). Why its needed. No need of this line just do let push = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController") as! testViewController
push.delegateTest = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push!, animated: true)

Comment: @Raja - happy to hear bro, accept any one answer if it is useful

Comment: @Raja  yea welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update these changes in `viewdidLoad()` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   if let push = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController") as? SelectionScreen
  {
    push.delegateTest = self
  }

}
```

Comment: what is the use of this `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push!, animated: true)`

Comment: Without type of class its not permit you to set 'delegateTest' So you need to write let push = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController") as! testViewController

Comment: @NimishaRanipa he was talking about self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push!, animated: true) that i removed not about the instantiation

Comment: Yeah.

I updated it as

       
 let selectionVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectionScreen") as! SelectionScreen
        selectionVc.delegateTest = self
        present(selectionVc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @Raja Yes Great its helps you

Comment: @NimishaRanipa yup certainly.

Comment: @harshaljadhav could you please update your answer as 

        let selectionVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectionScreen") as! SelectionScreen

I wish to make as a correct answer

Comment: sure i will edit the answer @NimishaRanipa Thanks for pointing the mistake

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are facing due to this line

```
let vw = testViewController()
    vw.delegateTest = self
```

You have created instance of testViewController **vw**, and Assigned delegate of vw instance

In the next line

```
let push = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push!, animated: true)
```

You are creating different instance of testviewcontroller **push**

There is no need of this code,

```
let vw = testViewController()
        vw.delegateTest = self
```

Instead do

```
let push testViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController") as! testViewController
push.delegateTest = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push, animated: true)
```

Comment: Without type of class its not permit you to set 'delegateTest' So you need to write let push = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController") as! testViewController

Comment: @NimishaRanipa - Thank you. I am updating the answer

Comment: @Raja - Welcome, you did great there are just two separate instance of testViewController, the instance you were pushing was not confirming to delegate.

Answer (score 2):

```
let vw = testViewController() // Your are doing wrong code 
vw.delegateTest = self
```

**Use only this**

I hope it will work for you

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let push = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"testViewController")as! testViewController
push.delegateTest = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet does not make sense. You just create an object but does not use it further. So remove this code snippet.

```
  let vw = testViewController()
        vw.delegateTest = self
```

And do like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let pushVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController") as! testViewController
 pushVC.delegateTest = self

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pushVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, you put code `func testMethod(value:String) {
    print("Hai", value)
}`

into viewDidLoad and above `let push = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "testViewController")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(push!, animated: true)`