# Protocol delegate not working within custom UIView button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have been trying to create a protocol and delegate within my custom UIView subclass, but when I call it on View Controller class the button is not responding to the method. I have read almost all the answers on StackOverflow, none of them solve my issue. Here is the procedure I have followed:

#### UIView Subclass **(View A)**

**Create the require delegate:**

```
protocol LoginDelegates {
    func loginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
}
```

**Within Subclass**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    var delegate: LoginDelegates? // Initite the delegate variable

    //Login Button Action
    @IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
       delegate?.loginButtonPressed(sender: loginButton)
    }
}
```

#### View Controller Class (View B)

Call the delegate within the class:

```
class AccessViewController: UIViewController, LoginDelegates
```

In here I tried multiple approaches I have found on SO and around web. but none of them seems to work for me, the button still doesn't respond.

**Approach 1:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Assign the delegate in current view
    let LoginView = LoginViewController()
    LoginView.delegate = self
}
```

**[Approach 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45815276/2556515):** 
with this approach, I get the following error  `doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'LoginViewController'`, which make sense cause the view is subclass and not within the storyboard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Assign the delegate in current view
    if let loginView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController {
        loginView.delegate = self
    }

}
```

and of course, call the method in the current view.

```
func loginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDashboard", sender: self)
}
```

I also try to create a swift file and just put all the protocols separate from both views and just call them when needed. and At this point, I have no other option. Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why your approaches aren't working, it should have worked. 
1. Check whether you IBAction is connected to UI or not, sometimes it got disconnect so try to reconnect if not connected.
2. Declare a Protocol as Class ( i mean Protocol LoginDelegates: Class) and declare delegate as a weak. Never give strong reference to delegate.

Comment: @JogendraSingh I know, it's weird. I'm willing to show anyone screen sharing of the project.

Comment: I updated the previous comment. again check it out.

Comment: You can share screen. will be happy to solve if I can.

Comment: @JogendraSingh I did all your recommendation, but no luck. When do you want to do TeamViewer?

Comment: You can't set the delegate in`viewDidLoad`.  You need to set it when you have a reference to the login view controller that is going to be presented. How do you preset the `LoginViewController`?

Comment: @Paulw11 in `LoginViewController` is set outside of `viewDidLoad` as `var delegate: LoginDelegates?`

Comment: @Paulw11 in AccessViewController is set as this image: https://ibb.co/ksJ2Rn The method just never called.

Comment: Hello @Farhad how did you solve your problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your LoginViewController like so:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    static weak var shared: LoginViewController?

    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: LoginDelegates? // Initite the delegate variable

    //Login Button Action
    @IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
       delegate?.loginButtonPressed(sender: loginButton)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // All your viewDidLoad stuff

       LoginViewController.shared = self

    }
}
```

Update your AccessViewController like so:

```
class AccessViewController: UIViewController, LoginDelegates {


   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // All your viewDidLoad stuff

      LoginViewController.shared?.delegate = self

   }

   func loginButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDashboard", sender: self)
   }
}
```

The problem you have caused because you don't have access to your active instance of LoginViewController. In both your approaches you create a new instance of LoginViewController but you need to access existing instance. To make this you have to create static variable which will keeps for you a reference to the active instance of the LoginViewController.

Also please remember that in most cases you have to mark delegate variable as weak to avoid memory leaks.

Because of you load and present view of your LoginViewController directly in AccessViewController view your LoginViewController is not the firstResponder. Because of this the action of your button is not called while pressing.

You can make some trick in your AccessViewController class

```
class AccessViewController: UIViewController, LoginDelegates {


   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // All your viewDidLoad stuff

      let loginVC = LoginViewController()

      loginVC.loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.loginButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

      //add your LoginViewController view as subview to your AccessController view.

   }

   @objc func loginButtonPressed() {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDashboard", sender: self)
   }
}
```

Comment: in `AccessViewController` I get the following error when I try yours **Cannot assign value of type 'AccessViewController' to type 'LoginViewController?'**. When I try `LoginViewController.shared = self `

Comment: @Xrait In AccessViewController you have to enter LoginViewController.shared?.delegate = self instead of LoginViewController.shared = self Please look carefully at the answer.

Comment: That got rid of the error, but still not running the method.

Comment: @Xrait, are you sure that you entered LoginViewController.shared = self in the viewDidLoad() of LoginViewController ??

Comment: Yes, I can do screen sharing if you like. here is an [image](https://ibb.co/fBVP6n) proof.

Comment: Are you sure that both view controller instances are active at the moment you press the button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169002/discussion-between-xrait-and-dmitry).