# Protocol Delegate between XIB and View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, xib

So I have XIB View and View Controller. I want when a button in my XIB clicked (`didTapTryAgain` Button), the called a function from my view controller. Then I tried to create a protocol and delegate for the class. But it still won't called my function. Here's my XIB view class:

```
import UIKit

protocol ErrorMessageDelegate {
    func refresh(_sender: AnyObject)
}

class ErrorMessage: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewError: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelError: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTryAgain: UIButton!
    static weak var shared: ErrorMessage?
    var delegate: ErrorMessageDelegate?
    static var message: String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        ErrorMessage.shared = self
        labelError.text = ErrorMessage.message
    }

    @IBAction func didTapTryAgain(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.refresh(_sender: buttonTryAgain)
    }
}
```

And here's my View Controller class:

```
import Foundation

class BaseViewController: UIViewController, ErrorMessageDelegate {

    func refresh(_sender: AnyObject) {
        print("I hope my function work here")
    }

    var uiView =  UIView();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ErrorMessage.shared?.delegate = self
    }

    func getErrorMessage(message:String) {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Dialog.dismiss()
        ErrorMessage.message = message
        guard let viewErrorMessage = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorMessage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ErrorMessage else { return}
        self.view.addSubview(viewErrorMessage)
    }
}
```

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834649/protocol-delegate-not-working-within-custom-uiview-button) for my code, and it still not working. Is anyone know how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you set the delegate for a shared instance here

```
ErrorMessage.shared?.delegate = self / here shared?. is nil
```

but here

```
guard let viewErrorMessage = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorMessage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ErrorMessage else { return}
self.view.addSubview(viewErrorMessage)
```

you create a separate instance and add it

You need

```
var viewErrorMessage:ErrorMessage! // add to the vc
```

---

```
viewErrorMessage = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorMessage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ErrorMessage 
viewErrorMessage.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(viewErrorMessage)
```

---

Also completely git rid of

```
static weak var shared: ErrorMessage?
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this code then your delegate method will be call.

```
  func getErrorMessage(message:String) {
    ErrorMessage.message = message
    guard let viewErrorMessage = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ErrorMessage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ErrorMessage else { return}
    viewErrorMessage.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(viewErrorMessage)
}
```

and call method where ever you want to open the popup

```
getErrorMessage(message: "Test Message")
```